# React and ReactDOM undefined but installed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm just trying to make a simple react app with a .tsx transpiler, but the react and react-dom are undefined upon import:

This is my entry file and only typescript file:

index.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

console.log(ReactDOM);

ReactDOM.render(<div>SUCCESS!</div>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Console output errors:

```
undefined
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'render' of undefined
```

The ReactDOM object is output as 'undefined' so the render() fails on undefined object. Installed the React and ReactDOM modules the normal way with 'npm install --save-dev react react-dom' and that verified both react folder exist under node_modules.

webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/js/index.tsx',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/dist'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [

  ]
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "helloworld",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Hello there",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack-dev-server",
    "build:prod": "webpack -p"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.2.3",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.19.0",
    "ts-loader": "^2.3.7",
    "typescript": "^2.5.3",
    "webpack": "^3.7.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: try `rm -rf node_modules` then `npm i`, check if it works

Comment: react and reactdom should not be dev dependencies... make them regular dependencies

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The proper syntax for importing all the exports of a module in TypeScript into a single name is:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```

(Notice the `* as` part)

The syntax you're using will instead import the `default` export, which React does not provide AFAIK. (Hence `undefined`.)

The situation is a bit confusing because IIRC babel will expose the whole `module.exports` object as the `default` export if no `default` export is provided, but TypeScript will not.

PS: Also make sure you install `@types/react` and `@types/react-dom` as dependencies via npm so you get full autocompletion and type checking.

---

*Edit (2018-04-04):* **As of TypeScript 2.7, the answer above is no longer entirely accurate.**

The new `--esModuleInterop` compiler option provides import semantics more closely aligned with Babel and with the ES6 modules spec.

With the option enabled CommonJS `module.exports` will be mapped to ES6 `default export ...` by the TypeScript compiler, so `import foo from 'bar'` should now work without any issues just like on Babel.

Keep in mind that `--esModuleInterop` is currently disabled by default to allow for a smoother transition, but the TypeScript docs recommend *enabling it for both new and existing projects.*

(You can enable it via the command line or via a *tsconfig.json* file)

Note: The `import * as foo from 'bar'` syntax is still valid, but it's now only used in the cases where you want to group all non-default exports under a single identifier. (Not as common)

For more info on the change and the problems it addresses, see the [Relevant section of the Release Notes for TypeScript 2.7](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#support-for-import-d-from-cjs-form-commonjs-modules-with---esmoduleinterop)

Comment: React _does_ provide default export.

Comment: Solved! Thank you Marco! I didn't know TypeScript did that.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue. In my case, this happens due to upgrading only react without React dom.

> For example - React: 17.x and React-DOM: 16.x

Try below command which helped to resolve this issue.

```
npm update react react-dom --depth 4
```